# golang: how to simulate union type efficiently

Tags: go

As known, go has no union type, and should only be simulated via interface.

I try two methods to simulate the union, but the result is far from good as C.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type U interface {
    i32() int32
    i16() int16
}

type i32 int32

func (u i32) i32() int32 {
    return int32(u)
}

func (u i32) i16() int16 {
    return int16(u)
}

type i16 int16

func (u i16) i32() int32 {
    return int32(u)
}

func (u i16) i16() int16 {
    return int16(u)
}

func test() (total int64) {
    type A struct {
        t int32
        u interface{}
    }
    a := [...]A{{1, int32(100)}, {2, int16(3)}}

    for i := 0; i < 5000000000; i++ {
        p := &a[i%2]
        switch p.t {
        case 1:
            total += int64(p.u.(int32))
        case 2:
            total += int64(p.u.(int16))
        }
    }
    return
}

func test2() (total int64) {
    type A struct {
        t int32
        u U
    }
    a := [...]A{{1, i32(100)}, {2, i16(3)}}

    for i := 0; i < 5000000000; i++ {
        p := &a[i%2]
        switch p.t {
        case 1:
            total += int64(p.u.i32())
        case 2:
            total += int64(p.u.i16())
        }
    }
    return
}

type testfn func() int64

func run(f testfn) {
    ts := time.Now()
    total := f()
    te := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(total)
    fmt.Println(te.Sub(ts))
}

func main() {
    run(test)
    run(test2)
}
```

result:

```
257500000000
1m23.508223094s
257500000000
34.95081661s
```

The method way is better, and the type-cast way cost more CPU time.

The C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
    int t;
    union {
        int i;
        short v;
    } u;
};

long test()
{
    struct A a[2];
    a[0].t = 1;
    a[0].u.i = 100;
    a[1].t = 2;
    a[1].u.v = 3;

    long total = 0;
    long i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5000000000; i++) {
        struct A* p = &a[i % 2];
        switch(p->t) {
        case 1:
            total += p->u.i;
            break;
        case 2:
            total += p->u.v;
            break;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
int main()
{
    long total = test();
    printf("%ld\n", total);
}
```

result:

```
257500000000

real    0m5.620s
user    0m5.620s
sys 0m0.000s
```

The union type is useful for many applications, e.g. network protocol may contains variant concrete type.
So maybe the access of union data may become the bottleneck of the application.

Anybody could help? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can use arrays to represent a single `int32` as two `int16`s and then assemble them with shifts [as Rob Pike recommends](http://commandcenter.blogspot.ru/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html):

```
func test3() (total int64) {
    type A struct {
        t int32
        u [2]int16
    }
    a := [...]A{
        {1, [2]int16{100, 0}},
        {2, [2]int16{3, 0}},
    }

    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        p := &a[i%2]
        switch p.t {
        case 1:
            total += int64(p.u[0]<<0 | p.u[1]<<8)
        case 2:
            total += int64(p.u[0])
        }
    }
    return
}
```

With the original Go compiler it runs about 2 times slower than the C version, and with gccgo (-O3) it runs about as fast as C.

Be warned though that this approach assumes little-endian ints. You'll need to switch the order of shifts for big-endian architecture.

Also, if you need to decode structures from a byte slice, you should really be using [`encoding/binary`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/). This library is created to translate between byte sequences and other types.

Comment: Yes, it may improve the performance, but sometimes the variant type may include other types, e.g. string or byte array.

Comment: See edit. I've removed uses of `unsafe` since it's not really needed and added a note about other types.

Comment: Thanks. I try the binary functions, they seems very expensive. Since the union is not intend to be wire format, so binary representation is not necessary for numeric types. I think unsafe make more sense in my case.

Answer (score 8):

I bet myself to make it much closer to C variant, and here's what I got:

`(full code)`

https://play.golang.org/p/3FJTI6xSsd8

thing is that we going through all struct's fields and redirect them to buffer's storage (which has compile-time len refereed from template struct, for sake of memory salvation and universality)

`result:`

```golang
func test() (total int64) {

    type A struct {
        t int32
        u struct {
            // embedded buffer of union
            FooSize

            // mark all types inside as pointer types
            i *int32 // long
            v *int16 //short
        }
    }
    var a [2]A

    // initialize them
    Union(&a[0].u)
    Union(&a[1].u)

    a[0].t = 1
    *a[0].u.i = 100
    a[1].t = 2
    *a[1].u.v = 3

    for c := 0; c < 5000000000; c++ {
        p := &a[c%2]
        switch p.t {
        case 1:
            total += int64(*p.u.i)
        case 2:
            total += int64(*p.u.v)
        }
    }

    return
}
```

// your bench:

```
257500000000
8.111239763s
```

// native bench (8,18800064s):

```
BenchmarkUnion         1        8188000640 ns/op              80 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

Ran it on $5 digitalocean droplet.

---

Implementation is cursed and may be not compatible with future versions of Go (current is 1.13), but usage (as behavior) is C-like, also supports any type (you can replace integers with structs as well)

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a small tool to generate C-style unions called `unionize` which you can find at https://github.com/zyedidia/unionize. You give it a template and then it will generate Go code that acts like a union and has comparable performance to C (warning: it uses the unsafe package, see the github repository for how it works and a detailed discussion of alternatives).

I copied your C benchmark into Go using unionize. First create a template for the union, for example in `union.go`:

```golang
package main

type Int struct {
    i int32
    v int16
}
```

Now use `unionize` to generate the actual union code which will go into `a_union.go`:

```sh
$ unionize -output=a_union.go Int union.go
```

This creates a new type `IntUnion` from the `Int` template which exposes functions to manipulate the union members. Now we can write the benchmark using that type:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    t int
    u IntUnion
}

func main() {
    var a [2]A
    a[0].t = 1
    a[0].u.iPut(100)
    a[1].t = 2
    a[1].u.vPut(3)

    var total int
    for i := 0; i < 5000000000; i++ {
        p := &a[i%2]
        switch p.t {
        case 1:
            total += int(p.u.i())
        case 2:
            total += int(p.u.v())
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(total)
}
```

When I time it I get:

```sh
$ go build main.go a_union.go
$ time ./main
257500000000

real    0m6.202s
user    0m6.197s
sys 0m0.012s
```

Not bad! (on my machine the C benchmark runs in roughly 3 seconds). The tool is fairly small, so let me know if there are more features you are looking for, or if you find any bugs.

Answer (score 3):

The union may contains numeric types and octet string, so I try to use byte slice as the value container and use `unsafe.Pointer` to access it according to the concrete type.

```
func test3() (total int64) {
    type A struct {
        t int32
        u []byte
    }   

    a := [...]A{{1, make([]byte, 8)}, {2, make([]byte, 8)}}
    *(*int32)(unsafe.Pointer(&a[0].u)) = 100 
    *(*int16)(unsafe.Pointer(&a[1].u)) = 3 

    for i := 0; i < 5000000000; i++ {
        p := &a[i%2]
        switch p.t {
        case 1:
            total += int64(*(*int32)(unsafe.Pointer(&p.u)))
        case 2:
            total += int64(*(*int16)(unsafe.Pointer(&p.u)))
        }   
    }   
    return
}
```

result:

```
$ go run union.go
257500000000
12.844752701s

$ go run -compiler gccgo -gccgoflags -O3 union.go
257500000000
6.640667s
```

Is it the best version?

Comment: Using arrays (or pointers to arrays) instead of slices could theoretically improve performance.

Comment: I try byte array, but the performance is almost the same. Anyway, in my case, the octet string is in variable length, so byte slice should be the only choice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which stores the union data as an `interface{}` and then uses a type switch to decide which data is stored in the union field:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    u interface{}
}

func test() int64 {
    a := []A{
        {u: int32(100)},
        {u: int16(3)},
    }

    total := int64(0)
    for i := int64(0); i < 5000000000; i++ {
        switch x := a[i%2].u.(type) {
        case int32:
            total += int64(x)
        case int16:
            total += int64(x)
        }
    }
    return total
}

func main() {
    total := test()
    fmt.Println(total)
}
```

Due to the use of the type switch, the field `t` is not needed, making the code a bit tidier than the C version.  This is still slower than the C code, but only by a factor of two.

C version:

```
257500000000

real    0m3.788s
user    0m3.776s
sys 0m0.011s
```

Go version:

```
257500000000

real    0m6.229s
user    0m6.211s
sys 0m0.019s
```